# mysqldump without stored function

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to restore a mysqldump from one server to another.  When I run the import:

```
mysql -u user -p < file.sql
```

I get the error:

> You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled

A quick google shows that i can fix it by setting:

```
SET GLOBAL log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1;
```

However, on the server I am importing to I don't have root privileges and my MySql account does not have sufficient permissions to make this setting.

I had a look at the manual page: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-logging.html

It seems that this error might be related to stored functions being imported and they are not enabled so it causes this error.

I ran this on original database:

```
mysql> SELECT ROUTINE_DEFINITION FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES WHERE ROUTINE_SCHEMA = 'mydatabase' AND ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE';
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

So it seems the original database has no stored procedures so why does this error occur?

I don't have root permissions on system I am importing to so can i solve this problem by altering the way I do the mysqldump?

How can I get the database import to work?

edit;

could this be caused by triggers?  I ran:

```
SHOW TRIGGERS;
```

on original database and it has triggers as results

Answer (score 2):

The `log_bin...` option must be set to true before you can create triggers or stored routines. If you don't have root privilege, you need to talk to your database administrator to set that option.

Another thing that requires SUPER privilege is the `DEFINER` clause that appears in stored routines, triggers, and views. You need to edit your schema definitions to remove these clauses.

This is quite inconvenient. I had to do this to restore databases on Amazon RDS, where I cannot have SUPER privilege. I had to break up the database restoration process:

1. Dump schema with no data and no triggers.
2. Filter output of schema dump to remove `DEFINER` clauses from stored routines and views.
3. Restore schema.
4. Dump data with no schema definitions.
5. Restore data.
6. Dump triggers.
7. Filter output of trigger dump to remove `DEFINER` clauses.
8. Restore triggers.